# Invalid argument: couldn't grab the accept mutex with apache

Tags: apache, mutex

** Running httpd-2.2.3 CQ5.6.1 centos 5.10**

Everything running fine but somehow apache got stop working, I checked by accessing via browser but not able to get the page. Apache error logs was showing below content:

```
[Wed Apr 29 11:56:11 2015] [emerg] (43)Identifier removed: couldn't grab the accept mutex
[Wed Apr 29 11:56:11 2015] [alert] Child 11750 returned a Fatal error... Apache is exiting!
[Wed Apr 29 11:56:14 2015] [emerg] (22)Invalid argument: couldn't grab the accept mutex
[Wed Apr 29 11:56:14 2015] [emerg] (22)Invalid argument: couldn't grab the accept mutex
[Wed Apr 29 11:56:14 2015] [emerg] (22)Invalid argument: couldn't release the accept mutex
[Wed Apr 29 11:56:14 2015] [error] [client 10.207.146.175] (104)Connection reset by peer: proxy: error reading status line from remote server, referer: 
[Wed Apr 29 11:56:14 2015] [error] [client 10.203.146.81] (20014)Internal error: proxy: error reading status line from remote server myserver2.com, referer: 
[Wed Apr 29 11:56:14 2015] [emerg] (22)Invalid argument: couldn't grab the accept mutex
[Wed Apr 29 11:56:14 2015] [emerg] (22)Invalid argument: couldn't grab the accept mutex
[Wed Apr 29 11:56:15 2015] [emerg] (22)Invalid argument: couldn't grab the accept mutex
[Wed Apr 29 12:01:15 2015] [error] [client 10.203.60.43] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: proxy: error reading status line from remote server myserver2.com, referer: 
[Wed Apr 29 12:01:15 2015] [error] [client 10.203.60.43] proxy: Error reading from remote server returned by /bin/servlets/FavFundsServlet, referer: 
[Wed Apr 29 12:01:15 2015] [error] [client 10.207.146.175] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: proxy: error reading status line from remote server unauth.myserver2.com, referer: 
[Wed Apr 29 12:01:15 2015] [error] [client 10.207.146.175] proxy: Error reading from remote server returned by , referer: 
[Wed Apr 29 12:06:15 2015] [error] [client 10.207.146.175] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: proxy: error reading status line from remote server unauth.myserver2.com, referer: 
[Wed Apr 29 12:06:15 2015] [error] [client 10.203.60.43] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: proxy: error reading status line from remote server myserver2.com, referer: 
[Wed Apr 29 12:06:15 2015] [error] [client 10.207.146.175] proxy: Error reading from remote server returned by /error/servererror.html, referer: 
[Wed Apr 29 12:06:15 2015] [error] [client 10.203.60.43] proxy: Error reading from remote server returned by /error/servererror.html, referer: 
[Wed Apr 29 12:06:15 2015] [emerg] (22)Invalid argument: couldn't grab the accept mutex
```

Could anyone please help me out what actually this relates with and why it happened and how can I fix this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I'm hitting the same, wondering if it might have been open files limit.

Comment: Same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/q/50652808/1405981?

Answer (score 0):

On XAMPP (Mac) click "configure" -> "open conf file" -> "yes", search "#Mutex default:logs", remove "#" and save. Now, start again Apache web server on your XAMPP (Mac).

It works for me.