# Apache shutdown - Couldn't grab mutex

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, apache2.4, ubuntu-18.04

For some reasons unknow to me, Apache is crashing.

This is the apache log at the moment of the crash:

```
[Sat Jun 02 02:38:05.196006 2018] [mpm_prefork:emerg] [pid 1122] (43)Identifier removed: AH00144: couldn't grab the accept mutex
[Sat Jun 02 02:38:05.196006 2018] [mpm_prefork:emerg] [pid 1116] (43)Identifier removed: AH00144: couldn't grab the accept mutex
[Sat Jun 02 02:38:05.198767 2018] [mpm_prefork:emerg] [pid 1115] (43)Identifier removed: AH00144: couldn't grab the accept mutex
[Sat Jun 02 02:38:05.199523 2018] [mpm_prefork:emerg] [pid 3924] (43)Identifier removed: AH00144: couldn't grab the accept mutex
[Sat Jun 02 02:38:05.204189 2018] [mpm_prefork:emerg] [pid 1937] (43)Identifier removed: AH00144: couldn't grab the accept mutex
[Sat Jun 02 02:38:05.207362 2018] [mpm_prefork:emerg] [pid 1120] (43)Identifier removed: AH00144: couldn't grab the accept mutex
[Sat Jun 02 02:38:06.057310 2018] [core:alert] [pid 1099] AH00050: Child 1115 returned a Fatal error... Apache is exiting!
[Sat Jun 02 02:38:06.057483 2018] [:emerg] [pid 1099] AH02818: MPM run failed, exiting
```

The last thing I did on the server lately was to install certbot to general HTTPS certificates for my sites.

Comment: I have the same problem, and it's happening on log rotate event

Comment: Have you fix this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

While Sean solution is valid, I learned another way to solve this problem.

First, you should know that this problem is related to using Certbot and SSL certificates on Ubuntu.

Now, to solve the problem without doing anything you're unsure of, simply do this (as root or with sudo):

1. Create the following file: `/etc/apache2/conf-available/mutex.conf`
2. Add `Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default` inside the newly created file
3. Enable new configuration file with `a2enconf mutex`
4. Restart Apache with `systemctl restart apache2` or `systemctl reload apache2`

But hey, it's already enabled by default! Why make a file just for that?

I though the same when I found this solution.

By one wonder or another, it seems that once your start using SSL certificates, this configuration line is somehow "ignored".
Thus, Apache fail to find the lock dir for the mutex file.

Just adding (remove comment) this line into `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` isn't working either.
You have to specifically create a configuration file and enable it.
Else it won't solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Please re-check your step 2 as it seems to be a typo. I had to use `a2enconf mutex-file` (without the conf).

Comment: @icasimpan Sorry for "nitpicking"... it may be a mistake, but I wouldn't classify it as typo.
A typo - under layman's terms at least - is something simply misspelled, mostly out of a hurry or sometimes out of disknowledge of the actual spelling - usually accidentally and not proof-read.

Comment: `it seems that once your start using SSL certificates, this configuration line is somehow "ignored".` Important precision I did not have this problem before using the SSL.

Answer (score 18):

I was experiencing the same error on Ubuntu 17.10 with Apache 2.4.27.

It appears to have to do with Apache talking to the OS about file locking. When I went into `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and added `Mutex flock` to the Mutex section (near the ServerRoot section), it seems to have solved the problem.

Unfortunately, all I can say is that this uses the flock() function (a system call?) to handle file locking. Per https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex

So it's a bit of a black magic fix in that I personally am not familiar enough with Apache's file locking behavior to say why it works, and I can only say it works because the Apache crash seems to have stopped, but only thus far. Nevertheless, it may help you and seems fairly low-risk.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will check this at a latter date. Will keep you updated.

Comment: Hello Sean. Just for your information, I answer this question with my own solution I found a while ago. Yours is still valid, but mind avoid to fiddle with unknow parameters. Take a look... ;)

Answer (score 5):

Below steps worked out for me in my case.

1. Connect to the server via SSH
2. Edit the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file. Below command I used nano editor and you can use your favorite editor

> sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

3. Search for "Mutex" section
4. Add the below line,

> Mutex posixsem

5. Save and close the file.
6. Check the configuration before restarting Apache service by running the command,

> sudo apachectl configtest

7. Restart the Apache service if everything is fine with above check,

> sudo service apache2 restart

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I have just updated Mutex to posixsem and seems to work fine. Need to test more. However, [apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex) says "The semaphore ownership is not recovered if a thread in the process holding the mutex segfaults, resulting in a hang of the webserver." which I don't understand. Do you have any idea about that?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared the complete log trace. It could be:

> [Sun Jul 21 15:49:43 2019] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: fork:
>   Unable to fork new process

This is due to low memory and apache failed to create new processes. It also depends on the number of processes you have configured it to fork. It happens when there is too much traffic on to the website.

Comment: I added all the lines related to the error. It's a problem related to the use of Certbot and SSL certificates. For one reason or another, once you use a SLL certificate, the `mutex` default value isn't "found", you have to set it manually. Creating a file `/etc/apache2/conf-available/mutex-file.conf` with `Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default` and enabling it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu 20 and apache 2.4.

Commenting the Mutex directive didn't solve the problem, but using **posixsem**, did.

So, I've added `Mutex posixsem` to my apache2.conf and the server stopped crashing.

Source: https://serverok.in/apache-ah00144-couldnt-grab-the-accept-mutex

Comment: Please refer to my own answer (with the `mutex.conf` file), it will solve your problem without doing anything you're unsure of. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58584916/6711360

Comment: Thanks @Preciel. Although I'm not using certbot, your solution was the second one I've tried. After doing yours, I started having another error `AH02026: Failed to acquire SSL session cache lock` that also make apache to stop. So, posixsem solved it until now.
I still have other errors related to Mutex, like `ModSecurity: Audit log: Failed to lock global mutex: Invalid argument`, but they don't hang up apache.