# failure apache2 http server

Tags: apache, vps

I don't understand a single thing of this. All I know and randomly happen and shut down my website. I can restart it but it always come back.

I can provide more details if you guys want to help. Thank you

```
 apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-02-16 13:47:11 CET; 32min ago
  Process: 5622 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 5633 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 16 13:21:26 vps754970 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Feb 16 13:21:27 vps754970 systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
Feb 16 13:47:11 vps754970 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 16 13:47:11 vps754970 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

That's my /var/log/apache2/error.log

```
[Sun Feb 16 13:21:27.135958 2020] [core:warn] [pid 5633] AH00098: pid file /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sun Feb 16 13:21:27.173307 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5633] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Feb 16 13:21:27.173349 2020] [core:notice] [pid 5633] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Feb 16 13:47:08.362978 2020] [mpm_prefork:emerg] [pid 5660] (43)Identifier removed: AH00144: couldn't grab the accept mutex
[Sun Feb 16 13:47:08.367067 2020] [mpm_prefork:emerg] [pid 5662] (43)Identifier removed: AH00144: couldn't grab the accept mutex
[Sun Feb 16 13:47:08.382882 2020] [mpm_prefork:emerg] [pid 5657] (43)Identifier removed: AH00144: couldn't grab the accept mutex
[Sun Feb 16 13:47:08.382622 2020] [mpm_prefork:emerg] [pid 5656] (43)Identifier removed: AH00144: couldn't grab the accept mutex
[Sun Feb 16 13:47:08.606868 2020] [mpm_prefork:emerg] [pid 5663] (43)Identifier removed: AH00144: couldn't grab the accept mutex
[Sun Feb 16 13:47:08.804351 2020] [mpm_prefork:emerg] [pid 5655] (43)Identifier removed: AH00144: couldn't grab the accept mutex
[Sun Feb 16 13:47:11.493608 2020] [core:alert] [pid 5633] AH00050: Child 5655 returned a Fatal error... Apache is exiting!
[Sun Feb 16 13:47:11.493772 2020] [:emerg] [pid 5633] AH02818: MPM run failed, exiting
```

Comment: here you go man

Comment: This looks related: [Apache shutdown - Couldn't grab mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50652808/apache-shutdown-couldnt-grab-mutex)

Comment: ok I have done thoses changes will see if it do the work. Thanks you.